# Passando um tipo criado em runtime para um metodo estatico

Tags: c#, reflexão, genéricos, dinâmico

**EDIT**

Meu problema é o seguinte.

Preciso gerar uma expressão lambda que seja de um tipo que só vou conhecer no momento de execução, ou seja, o tipo a ser usado será passado no parametro classType da controller abaixo. Porém o tipo que crio no método runtime não é compatível com a expressão que preciso criar.

OBS: o método WhereEqualsNonTyped reconhece o tipo do contexto gerado, mas quando se usa o typeof() ele retorna o tipo 'System.object'.

Abaixo a controller que chama o método para obter o tipo da classe dinamicamente:

```
 [Route ("{classtype} / {id} / {key}")]
    public string GetObter (int id, string key, string classtype)
    {
        var attach = servico.ObterDinamico (classtype, id, includes);
        return attach.RetrieveFiles (key);
    }
}
```

Método que cria o contexto a partir do tipo passado:

```
public object ObterDinamico(string typeName, int id, string [] includes = null)
    {
        Type tableEntity = Type.GetType ("My_Domain." + TypeName + ", My_Domain");

        IEnumerable <dynamic> dbObject = (IEnumerable <dynamic>)
                            typeof (DbContext) .GetMethod ("Set", Type.EmptyTypes)
                            .MakeGenericMethod (tableEntity)
                            .Invoke (bd, null);
        IQueryable <dynamic> result = dbObject.AsQueryable ();
        if (includes! = null)
            foreach (string i in includes)
                result = result.Include (i);
        return result.WhereEqualsNonTyped ("id", id, typeName);
    }
```

Método lambda que não reconhece o tipo T nesse caso, assim não gera a expressão como preciso:

```
public static IQueryable <T> WhereEqualsNonTyped <T> (this IQueryable <T> query, string propertyName, dynamic value, string typeName)
{
    try
    {
        //sem essa instancia do Type para gerar o tipo dinâmico que preciso 
        //o método sempre dá erro assim que chega na linha 
        //MemberExpression
        var type = Type.GetType ("My_Domain." + typeName + ", My_Domain");
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter (type, "type");
        MemberExpression property = Expression.Property (parameter, propertyName);
        BinaryExpression expression = Expression.Equal (property, Expression.Constant (value, value.GetType ()));
        Expression <Func <T, bool >> predicate = Expression.Lambda <Func <T, bool >> (expression, parameter);
        return query.Where (predicate);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return query;
    }
}
```

Atualmenteo erro que é gerado é:

> ParameterExpression do tipo 'My_Domain.my_object' não pode ser usada
>   para delegar o parâmetro do tipo 'System.Object'

Comment: No WhereEquals que tá o problema?

Comment: Isso, o método Obter acessa o setClass e cria uma instancia do objeto em tempo de execução. Porém quando a classe WhereEquals vai ser executada ela não consegue acessar essa intancia da classe dinâmica criada em tempo de execução, acessando uma instancia da classe Object.

Comment: E quando vai realizar a busca do atributo genérico passado é gerado o erro de atributo inacessível. E a expressão lambda não é gerada.

Comment: Tem um código que não é utilizado no Obter `SetClass`, tem um código com `dynamic` que no meu ver também não vai funcionar, talvez os problemas são antes, mas, faltou dizer qual o erro, tem como colocar na pergunta?

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(classType))  SetClass(classType);` o que esse código faz? e `IQueryable<dynamic> result = model?.AsQueryable();` aqui também está errado, aonde é utilizado e porque você fez assim? Lembrete: o único código correto é `public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T>` esse está certo, é desnecessário porque com a expressões já tem isso, mas, está correto!

Comment: O setClass ele recebe uma string e cria uma instancia de objeto através da string que é passada, até ai tudo bem. IQueryable<dynamic> result = model?.AsQueryable(). Esse trecho faz o seguinte, após gerar a instancia do objeto pelo método setClass, ele gera uma queryable do tipo passado e essa queryable é a que trabalhamos no método WhereEquals.

Comment: Eu não sei o contexto geral, mas, talvez seja isso que está faltando, do jeito que está ainda continua dando duvida dos outros métodos implementados! falta explicar mais na pergunta, colocar todo o código já é um bom começo.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta para que fique mais claro o problema.

Comment: Então, você fez um método de extensão, pra que instanciar um classe que já vem do próprio método? tem linguiça no seu código, de uma verificada isso não é válido... !!!

Comment: Só assim o código já funciona: como o código deveria ficar https://ideone.com/jnDd7p (só olhe o código o erro do site é normal)

Comment: Essa parte coloquei para verificar se o objeto que quero estava sendo gerado de forma correta, pois quando acesso o método WhereEquals ele perde a referencia do objeto e o mesmo se torna uma instancia do 'System.Object'. Foi mal, erro meu não ter explicado o porque de está gerando de novo no método WhereEquals.

Comment: Então, eu testei só o método de extensão em um código próprio e funciona, o problema não é WhereEquals é o método anterior que ao meu ver os dois são desnecessários, aonde se vai usar isso?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic quando o tipo do objeto está bem especificado na classe que chama o método WhereEquals ele funciona bem, o problema só ocorre quando tenho que gerar a instancia do objeto em runtime, como no exemplo. Pois o método não consegue identificar esse objeto dinâmico.

Comment: Guilherme Se o objeto que você quer gerar não estiver na classe de contexto não vai funcionar, o seu código é desnecessário sem ter uma necessidade mais clara, veja, eu estou tentando lhe mostrar que isso que você está fazendo é um má prática, porque, até agora não me mostrou um ponto funcional e da onde vai utilizar e para qual necessidade, é um objeto da classe ORM, ele deve existir se não provoca erros.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, vamos começar pela minha necessidade desse metodo. Possuo diversos objetos que atuam como "combos", ou seja, são compostos só por nome e id, e no mais uma outra variavel. E ao invés de gerar diversos contexts que atue para realizar a pesquisa de cada um desses objetos, esse metodo foi construído para isso. Porém no metodo Obter onde ele é instanciado encontrei o seguinte problema: o método whereEquals não consegue identificar o tipo da iqueryable que é gerada em runtime.

Comment: o erro é claro `IQueryable de dynamic` é uma camada `Entity Framework`que precisa de um tipo definido não vai funcionar! já começa o problema ai, sobre contextos, talvez existem formas melhores para fazer isso e com certeza existe.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic atualizei a pergunta, agora contém todos os metodos usados.

Comment: Olha talvez assim `public static dynamic GetInstance` troque para `public static T GetInstance<T>` e na última linha `return Activator.CreateInstance<T>(Type.GetType(fullName));` já mude bem isso para um objeto generico que deve estar contido na sua classe ORM. Eu dei mais uma olhada gerado , se está repetindo muito código dá para resumir tudo isso, mas, é um modo geral talvez essa modificação te ajude

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu até faria isso, porém da maneira que quero que o metodo trabalhe isso se torna inviável. Pois o tipo T será conhecido no momento da execução, ele vem como um parametro do front end. A partir disso tenho que gerar uma instancia desse objeto e realizar a busca.

Comment: Realmente não consigo te entender, porque, agora o tipo de dado vem do `Front-End` estranho isso, mas, como não tem como mexer pois é um problema local e sem reprodução fica complicado em eu te ajudar, desculpas!

Comment: Na verdade o tipo da combo a ser trabalhado sempre veio do front, porém não achei necessário passar essa parte aqui. Por isso tenho que acessar o metodo WhereEquals de forma mais generica possível. Mas desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic consegui resolver o problema de forma simples. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO**

Consegui resolver meu problema de uma forma bem simples, após algumas pesquisas extensas vi que meu problema na verdade era passar um tipo dinâmico gerado em runtime, para um método estático. E consegui resolver isso através da reflexão.

Abaixo segue o meu problema resolvido:

```
Controller que chama o método obterDinamico:
        [Route("{classtype}/{id}/{key}")]
        public string GetObter(int id, string key, string classtype)
        {
            var attach = servico.ObterDinamico(classtype, id, includes);
            return attach.RetrieveFiles(key);
        }
```

A resolução do problema, foi realizada no metodo obterTodos:

```
       public object ObterDinamico(string typeName, int id, string[] includes = null)
        {
            Type tableEntity = Type.GetType("My_Domain." + typeName + ", My_Domain");
            IQueryable<dynamic> dbObject = (IQueryable<dynamic>)
                                typeof(DbContext).GetMethod("Set", Type.EmptyTypes)
                                .MakeGenericMethod(tableEntity)
                                .Invoke(bd, null);
            IQueryable<dynamic> result = dbObject.AsQueryable();
//Chamo os metodos que preciso através da reflexão e com isso ele é instanciado com o tipo do objeto que é criado em runtime. Com isso meu problema foi resolvido
            MethodInfo notExcludeMethodInfo = typeof(ReflectionHelper).GetMethod("NaoExcluidos", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(tableEntity);
            MethodInfo whereEqualsMethodInfo = typeof(ReflectionHelper).GetMethod("WhereEquals", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(tableEntity);
            if (includes != null)
                foreach (string i in includes)
                    result = result.Include(i);
            result = (IQueryable<dynamic>)notExcludeMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { result });
            result = (IQueryable<dynamic>)whereEqualsMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { result, "id", id });
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Um dos métodos que são instanciados através da reflexão:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, dynamic value)
        {
            try
            {
                ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
                MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
                BinaryExpression expressao = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(value, value.GetType()));
                Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expressao, parameter);
                return query.Where(predicate);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return query;
            }
        }
```